# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Повторите своему ребёнку тысячу раз, что он дурак, и его подсознание примет эту программу как истинную.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна. Замените равнозначной по смыслу фразой: "Примет эту программу за истину". Запятой нет. А вот если мы сократим имеющееся предложение до предполагаемой запятой, его смысл утратится. "Примет эту программу". Что бы это могло значить? Явно не хватает информации. Это свидетельствует о том, запятая была бы лишней.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Запятая ставится в случае, если "как" вводит сравнительный оборот. А у вас обстоятельство (в качестве истинной).